# How can I create a million blocks in regtest or testnet?

Tags: mining, blockchain

Can anyone please tell me how to create a million blocks in regtest or testnet mode? Is there a way other than to start mining with the smallest difficulty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a private testnet and setting the difficulty very low is an easy way. You can start your testnet nodes passing the flag `--fixed-difficulty N` (where N is a very low number), so your mining node mines blocks near instantly.

There is also a new RPC command `generateblocks`, that can generate a bunch of blocks in regtest mode. It's currently not documented, but see the [commit message](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/34cb6b4b703f30be89388f4cdcc5d7b6780ee988). To use it, you would start `monerod` with the `--regtest` flag and the `--fixed-difficulty` flag (as detailed above). Then you can call the RPC interface passing the parameters: `amount_of_blocks` and `wallet_address`. For example:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d
  '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"generateblocks","params":{
  "wallet_address":"44GBHzv...","amount_of_blocks":1000000}}' 
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems with mining on regtest. I was getting `"status": "BUSY"` whenever I wanted to `/start_mining` or `generateblocks`.
In my case, the problem was that I was only running one node. It is hard to find any documentation or articles about Monero regtest, so I want to share my configuration.

First, run two `monerod` services.

First node:

```
./monerod \
    --regtest \
    --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 \
    --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:28080 \
    --fixed-difficulty 1 \
    --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 \
    --confirm-external-bind
```

Second node:

```
./monerod \
    --regtest \
    --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 \
    --p2p-bind-port 28080 \
    --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:18080 \
    --fixed-difficulty 1 \
    --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 \
    --rpc-bind-port 28081 \
    --zmq-rpc-bind-port 28082 \
    --confirm-external-bind
```

So basically you run first node with option `--add-exclusive-node` to restrict connection only to the second node. When starting second node, you point to the first one as its exclusive node. The rest of the config is just port settings.

After that you can also run a wallet:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc \
    --rpc-bind-port=18481 \
    --wallet-dir=/app/wallet \
    --rpc-login=rpcuser:rpcpassword \
    --rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0 \
    --confirm-external-bind
```

Wallet does not have `--regtest` option, so you just run it as if it was using mainnet.

Comment: Why are you using `--p2p-bind-port` only on the second node?

Comment: That was some time ago, so I'm not sure. Most probably because on first node default port settings are fine and on second node you cannot use the same ports as on first node, so defaults won't work and you have to specify custom port numbers.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Also, when I run two nodes as suggested, one of the node logs an error: "genesis block mismatch". Have you encountered such an error? I put it as a separate question: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/14192/genesis-block-mismatch-when-running-two-regtest-nodes-in-a-docker-container