# genesis block mismatch when running two regtest nodes in a docker container

Tags: monerod, regtest

So, I run 2 monerod nodes in a docker container, and one of them is giving the following errors:

```
2024-01-17 08:14:12.500 [RPC0]  ERROR   net.p2p src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:2436 Client sent wrong NOTIFY_REQUEST_CHAIN: genesis block mismatch: 
2024-01-17 08:14:12.501 [RPC0]  ERROR   net.p2p src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:2436 id: <48ca7cd3c8de5b6a4d53d2861fbdaedca141553559f9be9520068053cda8430b>, 
2024-01-17 08:14:12.503 [RPC0]  ERROR   net.p2p src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:2436 expected: <418015bb9ae982a1975da7d79277c2705727a56894ba0fb246adaabb1f4632e3>,
```

My monero config file:

```
# Documentation and examples:
# https://monerodocs.org/interacting/monero-config-file/

regtest=1
keep-fakechain=1  # keep the regtest blockchain, do not remove it after restarting the daemon
no-sync=1
offline=1 # ensures that the node does not connect to the main network and learn of its latest chaintip
fixed-difficulty=1 # keeps the difficulty constant, allowing a large number of blocks to be generated quickly

# Default is 0 = minimal logging; max is 4 - detailed tracing.
log-level=2

p2p-bind-ip=127.0.0.1
#data-dir=/monero/data

# RPC open node
rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0
# rpc-bind-port=18551
confirm-external-bind=1
restricted-rpc=0               # Turn off: Restrict RPC to view only commands and do not return privacy sensitive data in RPC calls
no-igd=1                       # Disable UPnP port mapping
hide-my-port=1
rpc-login=monero:monero        # username = monero, password = monero required to connect to API.
disable-rpc-ban=1              # Do not ban hosts on RPC errors.

# Slow but reliable db writes
db-sync-mode=safe

# As recommended at https://docs.monero.study/interacting/monerod-reference:
# Disable ZMQ RPC server. You should use this option to limit attack surface and number of unnecessarily open ports
# (the ZMQ server is unfinished thing and you are unlikely to ever use it).
no-zmq=1
```

Supervisor configuration file that runs the two monero nodes:

```
[program:monero-regtest-daemon-0]
# --non-interactive -- Do not require tty in a foreground mode. Helpful when running in a container.
# cannot be specified in config file.
command=monerod --non-interactive --regtest --log-file=/monero/logs/monerod0.log --config-file=/bitmonero.daemon.conf --p2p-bind-port=28080 --add-exclusive-node=127.0.0.1:28081 --rpc-bind-port=18550 --data-dir=/monero/data0
priority=500
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
stdout_logfile=/proc/self/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/proc/self/fd/2
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:monero-regtest-daemon-1]
# --non-interactive -- Do not require tty in a foreground mode. Helpful when running in a container.
# cannot be specified in config file.
command=monerod --non-interactive --regtest --log-file=/monero/logs/monerod1.log --config-file=/bitmonero.daemon.conf  --p2p-bind-port=28081 --add-exclusive-node=127.0.0.1:28080 --rpc-bind-port=18551 --data-dir=/monero/data1
priority=501
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
stdout_logfile=/proc/self/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/proc/self/fd/2
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve conflict: Ensure unique RPC bind ports and consistent data directory paths for Monero regtest nodes to avoid sending incorrect genesis block IDs.